# Why is this valid for modulus?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

My teacher asked if this statements was valid:

$$ 37 + 50 \equiv 27 \pmod {60} $$

Which is basically $$ 87 \equiv 27 \pmod {60}$$

and he said this is true. But how? I know that $87 \bmod {60}$ is $27$ but we didn't bring the mod over to the other side?

In a similar case he also said that this was not valid - $$17-35 \equiv 42 \pmod {60}$$

He didn't explain these statements at all, he just said them out loud with an answer and no explanation so I would appreciate some assistance in understanding this.

Comment: Did your teacher give the definition of what it means for two numbers to be congruent modulo $m$?

Comment: Saying that $a\equiv b \pmod m$ just means that $m$ divides the difference $(a-b)$.  I don't know why someone would dispute the third one...it seems perfectly valid to me.

Comment: In computer programs, it is actually written   87 % 60= 27. Equivalent of $87\equiv 27$ (mod 60). So we really do not have to bring mod to the LHS

Comment: I don't consider $\mod{60}$ to be a part of the left or right side of an expression. I consider it a clarification of $\equiv$. In other words, putting it at the end of an "equality" that uses $\equiv$ tells us what $\equiv$ means, but it doesn't "do" anything itself. One might as well have written something like $87\equiv_{60}27$ without any $\mod{}$ at all, and it's a pity that that is not the established notation, simply because the standard notation confuses people like it just did you.

Answer (score 1):

You must learn the definition of a modular statement.

If,$$a\equiv b\pmod c$$

then,by definition,

$$c|(a-b)$$ and the converse is also true.

$87\equiv27\pmod{60}$ is true because,$60|(87-27)$ or $60|60$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a \equiv b \pmod m \Leftrightarrow m|(a-b)$$

Comment: So if when we solve m divided by a-b we get 1 does that mean the statement is valid?

Comment: @Aceboy1993 No. $m|(a+b) $ means $m$ divides $a+b $

Comment: @N.S.JOHN So m|(a−b) should equal to 1 then? Because I did 87-28/60 and that equaled 1

Comment: @Aceboy1993 Not always. $60|(147-27)$ too. It should always give an integer when divided.

Comment: So then how do we know if the statement is valid? For example - 17-35=18 modulo 60 would not be valid but why?

Comment: @Aceboy1993 Because $(17-35)-18=-36$ is _not_ divisible by $60$.

Comment: @Arthur oh thanks, makes sense now